# Suppress replacement errors in R

Tags: r

I have a sequence of data frame subsetting operations. Some of them might fail because the rows to be replaced do not exist. I would still like the others to execute. Example:

```
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "bdp",]$party_id <- 32
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "svp",]$party_id <- 4
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "cvp",]$party_id <- 2
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "fdp",]$party_id <- 1
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "gps",]$party_id <- 13
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "sp",]$party_id <- 3
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "csp",]$party_id <- 8
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "pcs",]$party_id <- 8
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "party_id", value = 13) : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "lega",]$party_id <- 18
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "edu",]$party_id <- 16
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "glp",]$party_id <- 31
```

I would like the script to continue after the error has been thrown. I've tried using `tryCatch()` but that doesn't really help because I don't know in advance at which point the replacement will fail.

Is there a way to tell R to just "not care" about those replacement errors? And still continue with the next replacement operations?

The only solution I came up with is to use if-statements like this, which is tedious:

```
if(nrow(source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "lega", 1]) > 0){
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "lega",]$party_id <- 18
}
 if(nrow(source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "edu", 1]) > 0){
  source_data[source_data$abbr_d == "edu",]$party_id <- 16
}
etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is quite verbose code. Luckily, there is a way to get this done in a fraction of the code, and preventing your issue. My suggestion is to use a lookup table to build the `party_id` column

```
df = data.frame(abbr_d = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace = TRUE))
lookup_table = 1:8
names(lookup_table) = LETTERS[1:8]
# A B C D E F G H 
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

df$party_id = lookup_table[df$abbr_d]
```

So, you create the link between `abbr_d` and `party_id` once (here letters and simple numbers, but simply replace your values), and use the `df$abbr_d` column to subset the lookup table. This maps the labels in `abbr_d` to the values that correspond to that for `party_id`.

The error you see is avoided because only `addr_d` values that are actually in the data are looked up in the lookup table. These `unneeded` values in the lookup table do not pose an issue.

A `dplyr` approach as a bonus:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(party_id = lookup_table[abbr_d])
```

Comment: Cool, should have thought of that earlier!

Comment: @wnstnsmth Once you know things, it is easy to see ;).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `data.table` library to mitigate the issue

```
txt<-"
1,a,1
2,b,2
3,c,3
4,d,4
"
dat = read.delim(textConnection(txt),
header=FALSE,sep=",",strip.white=TRUE)
dat
dat[dat$V2=="e",]$V3<-4
# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "V3", value = 4) : 
#    le tableau de remplacement a 1 lignes, le tableau remplacé en a 0

library(data.table)
data=as.data.table(dat)
data[data$V2=="e",]$V3<-4
# no error thrown
```

data.table is often faster than data frame, afaik.